# How to export excel of selected record in Ignite UI in Angular

Tags: angular, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am using Ignite UI. In that I am using Igx grid, I am able to export excel of all data using `IgxExcelExporterService`, but I want to export only selected data by using `onRowSelectionChange` method of `igx grid`. Is there any way `igx-grid` support this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel Exporter service:

> this.excelExportService.`exportData`(this.data, ..).

Go ahead and pass a `data array` to the service. How to fill the data array with the selected rows data? Here you can find a code snippet for bootstrapping your POC:

Actual code:

```js
public clicked() {
  let selectedRows = this.grid1.selectedRows;

  for (let rowIndex of selectedRows) {
    let rowData = this.grid1.getRowByIndex(rowIndex).rowData;
    this.exportData.push(rowData);
  }
  console.log(this.exportData);
  this.excelExportService.exportData(this.exportData,
                                     new IgxExcelExporterOptions("ExportedDataFile"));

  this.exportData = [];
}
```

[This Export excel topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/exporter-excel) will help you any further.

Use this for a starting point with the [igxGrid row selection.](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/row-selection)